# package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have problem with import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection it say package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist and iam already put mysql-connector-java-5.1.36 at the netbeans

```
    package pkgnew;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author xxxx1
 */
public class DBConn {
    private Connection DBConn;
    public Connection connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connection Success");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println("Connection Fail" + cnfe);
        }
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars";
            try {
            DBConn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root","123456");
            System.out.println("Database Connected");
            }
            catch (SQLException se){
                    System.out.println("No Database"+se);
                    }
            return DBConn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Build the project after adding the jar to project properly

Comment: r u sure you have the MySQL jar file in  **classpath**?

Comment: You should usually have no need to cast a `java.sql.Connection` to a `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`, what you are doing is somewhat of an antipattern

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/nXmAJ7mf)

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn’t been needed since 2006.

Answer (score 0):

It's Jar missing issue.
Netbean Editor Unable to fine Classed from MySQL_XXX_whatever_Name.jar.

Please add properly required library first into your java project.

```
In Netbean, Right click on Library -> search Mysql...jar file(if exist from list) otherwise, manually download and import.
```

your problem will be solve out.

Comment: please, make sure about *.jar(mysql Driver's Jar). if it's not available then either manually download and import it into library. or if it's available into Netbean itself then great just import it.